# Control the sectional curvature

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Suppose $M$ a riemannian manifold with codimension $1$ and $p \in M$, the riemannian metric is inherited from
Eucildean space.

if there exist a sphere $S$(in Eucildean space) such that the center of $S$ is the original point and $S$ tangent to $M$ at $p$, in addition, there exist a neighborhood $V$(in $M$) of $p$ such that V is contained in the region whose boundary is $S$ in the Eucildean space . Will the sectional curvature of $M$ at $p$ bigger than the sectional curvature of $S$?

Thanks you for your answer!

Comment: My apologies, but I cannot make sense of your question. What are you referring to by 'the original point'? And from what I understand, your sphere $S$ is a sphere in the ambient space? or in $M$? If it is in the ambient space, how can it be the boundary of a closed ball in $M$ (since you wrote $V$ is a neighbourhood in $M$). That does not fit together with the statement that $S$ is tangent to $M$. Please check your setup.

Comment: @Thomas Sorry, my statement may be confusing, here the close ball is exactly living in the Eucildean space.Just image a small circle tangent to a big circle in Euclidean space and the small circle is contained in the region which is bounded by the big circle in the Eucildean space, this exactly what I mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might be asking the following: Suppose $M$ is a hypersurface in Euclidean space with the Riemannian metric induced by the Euclidean structure. Suppose that at a point $p$, there exists a sphere $S$ that is tangent to $M$ at $p$, and is such that there exists a neighborhood $V \subset M$ of $p$ that lies inside $S$. Then are all the sectional curvatures of $M$ at $p$ greater than the sectional curvature of $S$?

The answer to this question is yes.

One way to prove this is to show that the second fundamental form $H_M$ of $M$ at $p$ satisfies $$ H_M \ge \frac{1}{R}I, $$ where $R$ is the radius of the sphere.

Comment: Could you explain why this is true？Thanks！It's easy to image but I find I have no tool to prove it. Maybe I ignore something fundamental.